# F# projects in Visual Express 2013 Desktop

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, f#-3.1

I've found information it's possible to use F# in VE 2013 Desktop:
http://fsharp.org/use/windows/

I've installed both VE 2013 Desktop and F# Tools (using the links above), but when I launch the application I can't create F# projects - there are only VB, C#, C++ and SQL Server project.

However, I can open and successfully build F# projects that already exist (e.g. created on other machine with Visual Studio 2013).

What else shall I do to be able to create F# projects in VE 2013 Desktop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - after a while I realized I had had installed a VS Professional (90-day version) and then I uninstalled it in a wrong way - that's why my more recent version of VE got crazy.

Cleaning all the VS Pro files and reinstalling VE solved the problem.